# how to change the default look of a scrollview in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using a scrollview in my application. I want to know how can it be possible to change the default appearance of a scrollview(i.e a line) to something different, maybe an image or arrows in android.

Any kind of help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
HM

Comment: Not sure what you mean-- ScrollViews don't really have an 'apperance'; they simply allow you to scroll the inner view, whatever it may look like.

Answer (score 1):

hey it is in ApiDemos itself buddy. check this link [APIDemos/View/Scroll bars](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ScrollBar3.html)